# How to change the src or multiple images when the window size gets small

Tags: windows, ipad, image, src

I was wondering how to change the source of multiple images when the user changes the size of the browser window or they are using an IPAD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with pure CSS, using [CSS media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/). Instead of using `<img>` elements for your images, if you use background images on some block elements, you can easily swap their dimensions and background images by adding/removing classes (based on media queries -- and hence available client area) to their common container.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the user resizes the browser, the images are already loaded so there is no need to load a smaller version.

If they are using a smaller device eg ipad or iphone you can detect that and redirect to a different page where the images are the correct size for that device, eg ipad.example.com, m.example.com, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You do this with css3 media queries. Check out this article on [smashing magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)